# Laravel 5.7 - Access Notifiable inside view template

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.7

What is the correct way to access `$notifiable` inside my view template?

I understand `$notifiable` is the user but when I have the following

```
 public $abc;

 public function __construct($abc)
{
    $this->abc = $abc;
}


public function toMail($notifiable)
{

    $mailMessage = (new MailMessage)
        ->from('xyz@xyz.com', 'xyz company')
        ->subject('xyz')
        ->markdown('emails.news-alert');


    return $mailMessage;
}
```

Inside my blade template:

```
Hello {{ $notifiable->first_name }}

{{ $abc }}
```

The above throws an error because it doesn't recognize `$notifiable`

But if I pass it in as follows then it works:

```
$mailMessage = (new MailMessage)
        ->from('xyz@xyz.com', 'xyz company')
        ->subject('xyz')
        ->markdown('emails.news-alert', ['notifiable' => $notifiable);
```

Is `$notifiable` not a public property - I thought it was available to the view as default without needing to pass it through?

Comment: You've answered to yourself. Actually you just need to check `MailMessage` class [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.php#L97-L112) and you'll be aware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to send the variables to use in the view

```
$mail->markdown(
   'emails.news-alert', [
      'notificable' => $notificable,
      'abc' => $this->abc
   ]
);
```

some time you can use compact() helper but only when you have named variables (not $this->)

```
$abc = $this->abc;
$mail->markdown('emails.news-alert', compact(['notificable','abc']));
```

please try this and let me know how it works :)